# Insert missing comma (perl)

Tags: perl

Line:

```
výkonná produkce: Martin Scorsese, Timothy Van Patten střih: Kate Sanford, Tim Streeto herec(s): Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok)) Han Hee (Jang Mi Ryung) Kim Yoo Mi (Yoon Chae Yeon) Jae-ho Song (Im Bong Hoek (tatăl lui Sang Ok))
```

I want insert, with perl, missing comma like this:

```
výkonná produkce: Martin Scorsese, Timothy Van Patten střih: Kate Sanford, Tim Streeto herec(s): Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok)), Han Hee (Jang Mi Ryung), Kim Yoo Mi (Yoon Chae Yeon), Jae-ho Song (Im Bong Hoek (tatăl lui Sang Ok))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any details on constraints, we have to guess what you need. I'm guessing this:

```
s/\) /), /g
```